# Switch To Outlook Calendar using VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have a CustomTaskPane that I have added to Microsoft Outlook 2013.  This pane includes a WPF Calendar control that when double clicked I would like it to switch from the current Outlook view (Mail) to the Calendar view and go to the date selected in the control.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private void TopCalendar_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CalendarView calView = null;
    Explorer explorer;
    DateTime goToDate = (TopCalendar.SelectedDate.HasValue) ? TopCalendar.SelectedDate.Value : DateTime.Today;

    explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    Views views = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Views;

    foreach(View v in views)
        if (v.Name == "Calendar")
        {
            calView = (CalendarView)v;
            break;
        }

    calView.CalendarViewMode = OlCalendarViewMode.olCalendarViewMonth;
    calView.GoToDate(goToDate);
    explorer.CurrentView = calView;
}
```

However, when I double-click on a date the code is called (verified with breakpoint) but seems to have no effect on Outlook at all.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call [`Apply()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862662.aspx) to make the view the current view for the `Folder`. You also need to assign the [`CurrentFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866719.aspx) to the Calendar.

```cs
calView.Apply(); // applies the view
explorer.CurrentFolder = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar); // changes current folder
```