# VSTO: Open the calendar explorer in a new window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

i found this question: [Switch To Outlook Calendar using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957488/switch-to-outlook-calendar-using-vsto).

This works quite fine, but I want to open the Calendar in a new window to not change the users current window.

I could not find any information on how to do this, or if it is even possible. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found it:

```
 Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer();

 CalendarView calView = explorer.CurrentView;
 calView.CalendarViewMode = OlCalendarViewMode.olCalendarViewWeek;
 calView.GoToDate(date);
 calView.Apply();

 explorer.Activate();
```